# Geometry Nodes Simulation: Make point cloud react to Objects moving at a certain velocity

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I want the points to move away if certain objects are too close. But I want the points to change their velocity based on the objects velocity.
This is the complete node tree:
[image]

To reach my goal I thought to create instances of the real objects inside the simulation, change their position according to the real objects position, and then evaluate the position changes frame by frame to determinate their velocity. I made several tests through the spreadsheet and I believe this part is working well, storing a consistent velocity value in the instance:

[image]

The problem is when I try to apply the instance velocity to the points with the scale vector node (red arrow in the first screenshot), which always passes the value zero:
[image]

Here is the file:
[image]

Comment: *"I want the points to move away if certain objects are too close. But I want the points to change their velocity based on the objects velocity."* - in other words, you want points, within some range of the object, to follow that object? The closer a point is to the object, the more you want it to accelerate to the velocity of the object? *"The problem is when I try to apply the instance velocity to the points with the scale vector node (red arrow in the first screenshot), which always passes the value zero: "* - seems very easy to debug: either the vector input is 0, or the scalar input is 0